# Is it bad practice to use swing and awt together?

Tags: java, swing, awt

If so why?

What sort of conflict can come from this?

I am trying to minimise the weird errors you can get in java by finding out what the best practices are so hopefully using them will keep me out of trouble!

I have read a couple of swing vs awt threads but notice many examples of them being used together.

Motivation edit: I was taught to use both swing and awt together and I suspect that this may not be the best way.

Comment: This sort of question is generally not a good one for Stack Overflow. Why don't you be more specific about why you would want to use them together and then we can help you better. In general folks either use one or the other.

Comment: @FrancisUpton actually, I believe it is a perfectly valid question, there is even an article at http://java.sun.com devoted to this particular subject (which I have linked to down there in my answer)

Comment: I stand corrected, it's been a while since I have used Swing.

Comment: Why would you want to mix them together? What motivates this question?

Comment: @FrancisUpton *"I stand corrected"* I see nothing in your original comment that should be corrected.   1) The 'question' in total contains 3 questions - good for a 'Questions and general discussions' site, but not for a 'Question & Answer' site. 2) Good tip. 3) True - is is uncommon to mix AWT/Swing.  It requires an extraordinary need.  -- Can you expand about 'corrected'?  Note also that I upvoted the answer, and voted to close the question.

Comment: *"swing vs awt threads but notice many examples of them being used together."*  Give me the first five answers that mix Swing & AWT when the question does not.  People asking questions often make that mistake.  People basing their answers on the code in the question often do not notice the mix.

Comment: because I was taught to use them together, and found all sorts of weird happenings in my code. More and more I am thinking this is because of conflicts between the two that I have not been aware of. To show solid examples I would have to have more of an idea of the kind of thing that can go wrong. One time I had a weird code problem where it was repainting the whole frame/panel for no apparent reason. I had to put a Thread.sleep(x) in just to be able to see it. I have an idea this might have been caused by a conflict between awt and swing but I really don't know much about it to be sure.

Comment: Out of curiousity, exactly what is that thing that is pulling you towards using `AWT` that you couldn't find in `Swing` ?

Comment: I don't know how to add the panel to the frame in swing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the Swing component set provides alternatives to using pre-Swing  AWT components (such as Button, List, and the like), one of the primary  design goals for Swing was that it be based on AWT architecture.

Historically mixing heavyweight (AWT) and lightweight (Swing) components in the same container has been problematic. However, as of the JDK 6 Update 12 and JDK 7 build 19 releases, mixing heavyweight and lightweight components is easy to accomplish. [This article explains some details you might need to know.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html)

Comment: thanks that helps a bit... So, does this mean you have to be especially careful how you slap components on top of one another?

Comment: @Magpie - I think it means that you DON'T have to be careful ... if you use a recent JDK 6 or JDK 7.

Comment: but doesn't the heavyweight still show on top even with the update or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: @Magpie: Being careful on this is very easy. All swing components starts with a 'J'.

Comment: handy! But odd: If you are adding a panel (which is extending JPanel) to a frame then you could use getContentPane.add(panel); from the awt library, but shouldn't you be using something from swing?